# how to apply css style for pager control after selection of page?

Tags: c#, javascript, css, asp.net-mvc

I am using paging to my table grid.

```
<div class="divpager"> <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.TotalPages; i++)
  {%>
    <a  style="text-decoration:underline; color:Black" class="Pager"><%: i+1 %></a>
  <% }%>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.divpager {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I want whenevr user click on page need to apply css style as without underline. For that i tried `a.hover`, `a.active` as `text-decoration:none`. But i am not able to get. please tell me when click on page no need to show underline.

Comment: can you write you `Pager` class that you applied to links?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some jquery for this.. only CSS cant do this.

**CSS:**

```
.active { text-decoration: none !important;}
```

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.divpager a').click(function(){
    $('.divpager a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Don't forget to include jquery library in your page.

Comment: in click function i am calling showresults()to load the data.i tried above style but not applying .

Comment: I hope you have added jquery library in your page before this code.. can you show your code in fiddle ?

Comment: in masterpage only i added the jquerylibrary.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43740/discussion-between-era-and-user3106578)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try a:active?. Doing that you can style the link differently when you click on that element.

Something like

```
.Pager:active{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First, its a:hover, a:active, not a.hover, a.active;
2. Second, inline style has priority over the internal and external stylesheet.